# Query not functioning with LIKE

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand, sql-like

I'm running a query via `C#` using an `SqlCommand`. One for of the query performs as expected, but when I complicate it, I'm getting strange results that don't seem to make sense. I'm hoping someone is this community can make more sense of it than I am right now.

The below code runs fine, finding any record with the title containing the supplied text.

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_records WHERE Title LIKE '%' + @title + '%'";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Request.QueryString["idortitle"]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", Request.QueryString["idortitle"]);
```

However, when I add the below section, the only results returned are those matching the id. The results that partial-match the title are excluded. Why is this happening?

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_records WHERE Title LIKE '%' + @title + '%' OR Id=@id";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", Request.QueryString["idortitle"]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", Request.QueryString["idortitle"]);
```

Comment: Try bracketing the like construct? `SELECT * FROM tbl_requests WHERE (Title LIKE '%' + @title + '%') OR Id=@id`

Comment: @patrick Apologies. That was a copy paste error. I've corrected above. Good catch!

Comment: @Asad Tried that earlier, but no change.

Comment: @Patrick Sql injection attacks is why I'm using parameterized strings. Where is the issue with that? I'm interested to know.

Comment: @steventnorris - paremeters won't do anything to help you if you're using them as concatanated strings.

Comment: Your parameter names need to be `@title` and `@id`, not `title` and `id`

Comment: Problem solved. Posted answer below. I cannot accept for 2 more days, but if someone will repost my answer, I'll be glad to accept from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter being based was non-numeric, and the query was erroring without throwing an error due to the id field being numeric. When a check is added to ensure only numeric responses are used to check against the ID field, the code works. See below code:

```
int x;

            comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_requests WHERE Title LIKE '%' + @title + '%'";
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", Request.QueryString["idortitle"]);
            if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["idortitle"],out x)){
                comm.CommandText += " OR RequestId=@id";
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", x);
            }
```

Comment: There is an easier way to enforce parameter type. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the wildcards in the value of the parameter instead of using them in the query:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_records WHERE (Title LIKE @title) OR (Id=@id)";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request.QueryString["idortitle"]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", "%" + Request.QueryString["idortitle"] + "%");
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, this has not worked for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code instead:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_records WHERE Title LIKE '%@title%' OR Id = @id";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request.QueryString["idortitle"]);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", Request.QueryString["idortitle"]);
```